# MAMP PHP config file help

Tags: php, mamp, ini

When I modify the php.ini document found in

Applications/MAMP/conf/php5/php.ini

The changes are not reflected in the php info page in the MAMP interface

WHY?

Comment: Try restaring Apache ...

Comment: Had exactly the same problem, ended up being some rogue apache processes that hadn't been killed, even though I had stopped the server via the control panel.

Answer (score 6):

You need to restart MAMP (Or indeed any Apache Server) for changes in php.ini to take effect. Restart MAMP using the GUI.

If you are still experiencing no changes, it's possible you are editing the wrong php.ini file. In MAMP, each php version has it's own php.ini file.

To make utterly sure you are editing the right php.ini file, use the following steps:

1. Create a new .php file in your favourite text editor.
2. Type

   ```
   <?php phpinfo(); ?>
   ```

   and save it in MAMP's htdocs directory.
3. Save it as index.php
4. Make sure MAMP is running!
5. Start Safari, or any browser, and type "localhost:8888" into your
   URL bar.
6. You should see a purple table filled with information about your
   apache server.
7. The 6th row should be titled "Configuration File (php.ini)", and on
   the right of this, a path should be displayed to the php.ini file apache is
   currently using. It should look like this:
   "/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.4.4/conf"
8. Now, either use Finder to look browse to this location and edit the
   .ini file with Text Edit, or use Terminal.
9. If you want to use Terminal, open a new window and type the
   following:  'cd (and then copy and paste the path you gained from
   step 6)'. It should look like something like this: 'cd
   /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.4.4/conf'
10. Now type 'ls'
11. Typing ls will show you the files within the 'conf' directory. The
     correct php.ini file should be displayed amongst other files such as 'pear.conf'. If you can
     see 'php.ini', we're nearly there. If not, you've gone wrong somewhere, so
     read over the previous steps.
12. Now type 'sudo nano
     /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.4.4/conf/php.ini'
13. And give Terminal your password when it asks for it
14. The php.ini file will be opened in
          Terminal's integrated text-editor, nano. Edit it, and save it using
          Nano.
15. Simply quit terminal. 15) Restart Apache using MAMP's GUI 16)
     Browse to localhost:8888 in your favourite browser. Your changes
     should be reflected in the configuration screen.

I understand this instructions may be hard to follow, but just contact me if you want to use team viewer or something to get this working! Good luck

Comment: My phpinfo shows 7.2.14, and that's the one I am editing. Restarted entire MAMP a few times. Doesn't work. PHP still shows upload max at the default 8MB.

Comment: This works for me in 2022. Excellent way to figure out which php.ini is being used in any configuration, not just MAMP, any other server.

Answer (score 1):

Possible answers:

- You forgot to restart the Apache
  webserver after the change
- PHP uses a
  php.ini from a different location (Check
  the PHPIniDir setting in your Apache
  config).

Answer (score 0):

It seems that there are 2 php.ini files in the MAMP installation. The one that seems to be parsed in my case is not in the `config/` folder but in the `bin/php/php5.3.14/conf/php.ini`